How to optimize LCP in React + Webpack 5
I'm woking on a React (v18) project in a Microfrontend architecture with Single-SPA and Wepack 5.
I'm running Lighthouse on localhost and I get that the LCP takes too much and that the render is over 95% of the total time.
I've tried all sorts of things to improve this to no avail: I've implemented webpack plugins, code-splitting all my dependencies and react lazy loading. Doing this the score improved generally speaking, but I don't understand how to approach the LCP optimization. I don't seem to find much information online, and books are a bit outdated.
I would appreciate any guidance and resources on improving this issue.

